# "WriteLine" stop writing a file. (Windows PowerShell)

Tags: windows, powershell, streamwriter

I am trying to create a script for the university, that sorts the number of processes in the system by their handles number and saves them in a file. So far so good, sounds easy. But when I thought I had it finished, I realized that "WriteLine" stops writing when a few processes are missing and leaves the output incomplete. I have already checked by debugging that the process list is OK, but I can't figure out what is causing the problem.

Here is the code and the output:

```
# Comprobación de la existencia del directorio C:\Temp
if (-not (Test-Path -Path "C:\Temp" -PathType Container)) {
    Write-Host "El directorio C:\Temp no existe. Abortando la ejecución del script."
    exit
}

# Solicitar el nombre del fichero de salida y cargarlo en la variable $Fichero
$Fichero = Read-Host "Introduzca el nombre del fichero de salida"

# Generación de una línea en blanco en la consola
Write-Host ""

# Guardar en el array $Procesos todos los procesos en ejecución ordenados por su número de handles
$Procesos = Get-Process | Sort-Object -Property HandleCount

# Creación del fichero informativo

    # Abrir o crear el archivo en C:\Temp\$Fichero.txt para escritura
    $handle = [System.IO.File]::Open("C:\Temp\$Fichero.txt", 'OpenOrCreate', 'ReadWrite')
    $writer = New-Object System.IO.StreamWriter($handle)

    ######## Procesos entre 0 y 100 ########
    # Escribir en el fichero el intervalo de procesos
    $writer.WriteLine("######## Procesos entre 0 y 100 ########")

    # Escribir en el fichero una cabecera apropiada para la tabla de procesos
    $writer.WriteLine("{0,-10} {1,-40} {2,20}", "Id", "Nombre", "Número de handles")
    $writer.WriteLine("{0,-10} {1,-40} {2,20}", "==" * 4, "==" * 10, "==" * 19)

    # Escribir en el fichero informativo los procesos cuyo Nº de handles se encuentre entre 0 y 100
    # Para ello, se utilizará un bucle foreach.
    foreach ($p in $Procesos) {
        if ($p.HandleCount -ge 0 -and $p.HandleCount -le 100) {
            $Linea = "{0,-10} {1,-40} {2,20}" -f $p.Id, $p.ProcessName, $p.HandleCount
            $writer.WriteLine($Linea)
        }
    }

    $writer.WriteLine("")

    ####### Procesos entre 101 y 1000 ########
    # Escribir en el fichero el intervalo de procesos
    $writer.WriteLine("####### Procesos entre 101 y 1000 ########")

    # Escribir en el fichero una cabecera apropiada para la tabla de procesos
    $writer.WriteLine("{0,-10} {1,-40} {2,20}", "Id", "Nombre", "Número de handles")
    $writer.WriteLine("{0,-10} {1,-40} {2,20}", "==" * 4, "==" * 10, "==" * 19)

    # Escribir en el fichero informativo los procesos cuyo Nº de handles se encuentre entre 101 y 1000
    foreach ($p in $Procesos) {
        if ($p.HandleCount -ge 101 -and $p.HandleCount -le 1000) {
            $Linea = "{0,-10} {1,-40} {2,20}" -f $p.Id, $p.ProcessName, $p.HandleCount
            $writer.WriteLine($Linea)
            Write-Host $Linea
         }
      }


####### Procesos de 1001 o mas ########
    # Escribir en el fichero el intervalo de procesos
    $writer.WriteLine("####### Procesos de 1001 o mas ########")

    # Escribir en el fichero una cabecera apropiada para la tabla de procesos
    $writer.WriteLine("{0,-10} {1,-40} {2,20}", "Id", "Nombre", "Número de handles")
    $writer.WriteLine("{0,-10} {1,-40} {2,20}", "==" * 4, "==" * 10, "==" * 19)

    # Escribir en el fichero informativo los procesos cuyo Nº de handles se encuentre de 1001 o mas
    foreach ($p in $Procesos) {
        if ($p.HandleCount -ge 1001) {
            $Linea = "{0,-10} {1,-40} {2,20}" -f $p.Id, $p.ProcessName, $p.HandleCount
            $writer.WriteLine($Linea)
            Write-Host $Linea
         }
      }
    Write-Host "Fin"
    $writer.WriteLine("Final")


    $handle.Close()
```

The output in the file:

[image]

And the real output I want:
[image]

Thanks for your help.

I have tried to do it through:

```
Add-Content $path "###################### Processes between 0 and 100 handles #####################"


# Write in the file an appropriate header for the process table.
 Add-Content $path ('{0,-25} {1,-25} {2,25}' -f "Id", "Name", "Number of handles")

 Add-Content $ruta ("=============================================================================")

# Write in the info file the processes whose number of handles is between 0 and 100.
# between 0 and 100. To do this, a foreach loop will be used.

# Inside the loop body, the information # corresponding to each process will be generated in the variable $Line.
# corresponding to each process. Extended string formatting will be used to # format each line appropriately.
# will be used to format each line appropriately.
foreach($linea in $Processes)
{
    if(($linea.handles -ge 0) -and ($linea.handles -le 100)){
        $id=$linea.Id
        $name=$linea.Name
        $nHandles=$$linea.Handles
        Add-Content $path ('{0,-25} {1,-25} {2,25}' -f $id,$name,$nHandles)
    }
```

And this works but i need to do it with the other form.

Comment: Why do you want to do this instead of exporting the result to CSV or using `Format-Table | Out-String | Set-Content..` ?

Comment: Its just and exercise for university, and the want to use a .txt and this type of format in commands :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue with your code is that you're calling `$handle.Close()` closing the `FileStream` but without calling `$writer.Dispose()` first which will ensure the remaining buffer to be written to your file.

`StreamWriter` buffers data until it reaches a limit and writes that buffered data as a whole (default buffer size is 1024 chars, see [`streamwriter.cs`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/streamwriter.cs,48)). This is not the case if for example we enable [`AutoFlush`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamwriter.autoflush?view=net-8.0#system-io-streamwriter-autoflush).

It is also recommended to use `.Dispose()` instead as this method already calls `.Close()` internally. The following pattern would be the way you should do it implementing a [`try / catch / finally`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_try_catch_finally?view=powershell-7.3).

```bash
try {
    $Procesos = Get-Process | Sort-Object -Property HandleCount
    $handle = [System.IO.File]::Open("$pwd\test.txt", 'OpenOrCreate', 'ReadWrite')
    $writer = New-Object System.IO.StreamWriter($handle)
    # do stuff here...
}
catch {
    # error handling here
    Write-Error -Exception $_
}
finally {
    # dispose stuff
    if($writer) {
        $writer.Dispose()
    }

    if($handle) {
        $handle.Dispose()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, you have solved the problem perfectly.

And thank you also for the extra information, it has helped me to understand and learn more.